# github - Adding a file to branch

Tags: github

So I'm following these instructions: http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2008/using-git-and-github-on-os-x, and so far I've cloned the project I want to work on and created a branch.

Now I wish to add files that exist in another folder on my machine, but I keep getting the following:

> fatal: pathspec 'Users/mic/OnePageCRMVC/MKTsite25-05/index.html' did not match any files

However, the file definitely does exist...
Am I trying to do something that is not allowed and the error message is throwing me off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add them automagically. You should copy the files into the git repo manually, then do a normal add/commit.

Comment: Thank you... I had thought of that after posting.

Comment: No problems... git is wonderful once you get into it a little bit. Here's a guide that helped me a lot with it: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/